# Automatic synchronization of FTP server and local folder

Tags: ftp, remote-access, data-synchronization

I have a batch(Jenkins) that regularly(every 6 hours) check a folder on FTP Server and download files to local folder due to inconsistent upload time.

I was wondering if there is a way to detect changes or upload on the folder on FTP server and automatically download those files to local instead of simply access to FTP server and download the whole folder on quarter-day bases.

I also looked up a method using windowSCP and VSCode but those are mostly about updating FTP server when there is change in local folder or just checking the server on regular bases.

Please share any related information or idea. It would be greatly appreciated.